# How to base.RequestContext.ToOptimizedResultUsingCache() return string for Accept-Encoding: deflate?

Tags: servicestack

I do have following code...
and **Accept-Encoding: deflate**

```
public object Get(DTOs.Product request)
 {
    ...


    var sCache = base.RequestContext.ToOptimizedResultUsingCache(
    this.CacheClient, cacheKey, expireInTimespan, () =>
    {            
        // Business layer returns resultant dataset as XmlDocument
        ...

        return sXML.InnerXml;
    });

    //returns ServiceStack.Common.Web.HttpResult;
    return GenerateResp(sCache, base.Request.Headers["Accept"]);            
 }
```

Issue is *base.RequestContext.ToOptimizedResultUsingCache* returns *ServiceStack.Common.Web.CompressedResult* even though I am returning XML. I understand that **Accept-Encoding: deflate** causes **RequestContext.CompressionType** to **deflate**.

Above code works fine, when there is no Accept-Encoding (through fiddler test).

But, if the request comes from a browser, it would come as a Compressed, in this case how can I get sCache as string to pass it to GenerateResp?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to resolve the issue by modifying code to...

```
public object Get(DTOs.Product request)
{
    ...

    var objCache = base.RequestContext.ToOptimizedResultUsingCache(
                      this.CacheClient, cacheKey, expireInTimespan, () =>
    {            
        // Business layer returns resultant dataset as XmlDocument
        ...

        return sXML.InnerXml;
    });

    string compressionType = base.RequestContext.CompressionType;
    bool doCompression = compressionType != null;
    string transformed = "";

    if (doCompression)
    {
        byte[] bCache = ((ServiceStack.Common.Web.CompressedResult)(objCache)).Contents;
        transformed = bCache.Decompress(base.RequestContext.CompressionType);
    }
    else
    {
        transformed = (string)objCache;
    }

    //returns ServiceStack.Common.Web.HttpResult;
    //In GenerateResp, If compressionType contains "gzip" or "deflate", I compress back the response to respective compression, and add respective Content-Encoding to the header.
    return GenerateResp(transformed, base.Request.Headers["Accept"], compressionType);            
}
```

Thank you.